# MATLAB - tricky ode system with boolean

Tags: matlab, boolean, derivative

EDITED: Thanks for upvotes, now i finally added images. Added full m.file, although i don't think it wass necessary. The key of the code is.

```
xp(2)=...-((x(2)>=X2)&(xp(3)>=0)...; 
xp(3)=...-((x(3)>=X3)&(xp(2)>=0))...;
```

Full code:

```
function xp=uzdevums1(t,x)
%parametr values
r1 = 0.1; r2 = 1; r3 = 0.2;
K1=100;K2 = 100; K3 = 100;
X2=25;X3=10;
speedx2 = 0.02; speedx3=0.02;
%ode system
xp=zeros(3,1);
xp(1)=r1*(1-x(1)/(x(2)+x(3)))*x(1);
xp(2)=r2*(1-x(2)/K2)*x(2)-((x(2)>=X2)&(xp(3)>=0)&xp(1)>0)*x(2)*x(1)*speedx2; 
xp(3)=r3*(1-x(3)/K3)*x(3)-((x(3)>=X3)&(xp(2)>=0))*x(3)*x(1)*speedx3;
```

from shell:
    [T,X]=ode45('uzdevums1',[0 60],[10 80 20]);
The idea is that boolean expression in xp(2) (derivative of green line) should be true until it approaches X2=25, but
boolean expression for xp(3) (derivative of red line) should be false until xp(2) changes sign.

Red line = x3 does fine.. as the sign for xp(2) changes, boolean epxression is now true and red line changes direction, but green line fails to do so... in other words both x(2)>=X2 (which is fine) and xp(3)>=0 (which i don't understand)

in other words: red line is falling, how comes xp(3)>=0 ?

In 2nd picture i added xp(1)>0 and boolean expression finally become false... but why not at as xp(3) changed sign?!

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wait, I don't see any link to your images though.. how can we understand the question?

Comment: Is this code part of your model equations? If so, that's a really bad idea. The usual solvers do not expect discontinuous changes in your right hand side. You would need discretization, but since the intervals depend on your parameters this would require furthermore stuff like constraints and possibly time transformation. Not sure what you are trying here.

Comment: I wanted to attach image, but software didn't let as i don't hvae enough points.

Comment: I haven't had problems with solvers.. ode45 has worked great for me.

Comment: if you can't post images, you could at least post a little more of your code

Comment: 1. I feel like I've lived this post before... deja-vu all over again... 2. I need you to clarify what you need and what went wrong, e.g. don't say: `boolean expression in xp(2) should be true until it approaches X2=25`, but rather `the condition in xp(2) is true when X2 > 25`. The "approaches" word is personally annoying me because it doesn't mean anything without context. This is not abstract math, it's numerical computations, you must define everything.

Comment: Finally your whole code just feels wrong, I'm not sure if you're trying to do too much at the same time, but your derivative term has the potential of becoming psychotic if it were human. Booleans and differential equations need to be used with caution so that you don't have rapid transitions between the on and off state (those crazy vibrations you see in your plot). I can't fix it unless you clarify your conditions

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the main thing you want help with is an explanation of why the statement `xp(3)>=0` evaluates to true.

Study your calculations of `xp` step-by-step.

```
xp=zeros(3,1);
xp(1)=r1*(1-x(1)/(x(2)+x(3)))*x(1);
xp(2)=r2*(1-x(2)/K2)*x(2)-((x(2)>=X2)&(xp(3)>=0)&xp(1)>0)*x(2)*x(1)*speedx2; 
xp(3)=r3*(1-x(3)/K3)*x(3)-((x(3)>=X3)&(xp(2)>=0))*x(3)*x(1)*speedx3;
```

You try to use the value of `xp(3)` when you calculate `xp(2)` (and vice versa). But `xp(3)` is still zero when you use it in the calculation of xp(2), so the expression `xp(3)>=0` will always evaluate to true.