# ODE 15s with time dependent input parameters

Tags: matlab, ode

I have a MATLAB code that solves a large scale ODE system of following type

```
     function [F] = myfun(t,C,u)
```

u here is a time dependent vector used as a input in the function myfun. My current code reads as:-

```
 u    = zeros(4,1);
 u(1) = 0.1; 
 u(2) = 0.1;
 u(3) = 5.01/36;
 u(4) = 0.1;

C0            = zeros(15*4*20+12,1);
options = odeset('Mass',Mf,'RelTol',1e-5,'AbsTol',1e-5);
[T,C]   = ode15s(@OCFDonecolumnA, [0,5000] ,C0,options,u);
```

I would like to have the entire time domain split into 5 different sections and have the elements of u take different values at different times(something like a multiple step function). what would be the best way to code it considering that I later want to solve a optimization problem to determine values of u for each time interval in the domain [0,5000].

Thanks

Comment: Changing parameters of an ODE discontinuously is usually not a good idea  (and violates the mathematical smoothness requirements for ODEs) if you're looking for correct and accurate results – even using a stiff solve like `ode15s`. The way to do this is with separate piecewise integrations in time, stopping and starting the integrator for each. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17370733/2278029) and let me know if it helps. Also note how I pass parameters via an anonymous function rather than the deprecated method of adding them after the options input.

Answer (score 3):

`ode15s` expects your model function to accept a parameter `t` for time and a vector `x` (or `C` as you named it) of differential state variables. Since `ode15s` will not let us pass in another vector `u` of control inputs, I usually wrap the ODE function `ffcn` inside a `model` function:

```
function [t, x] = model(x0, t_seg, u)
    idx_seg = 0;
    function y = ffcn(t, x)
      % simple example of exponential growth
      y(1) = u(idx_seg) * x(1)
    end
    ...
end
```

In the above, the parameters of `model` are the initial state values `x0`, the vector of switching times `t_seg`, and the vector `u` of control input values in different segments. You can see that `idx_seg` is visible from within `ffcn`. This allows us to integrate the model over all segments (replace `...` in the above with the following):

```
t_start = 0;
t = t_start;
x = x0;
while idx_seg < length(t_seg)
    idx_seg = idx_seg + 1;
    t_end = t_seg(idx_seg);
    [t_sol, x_sol] = ode15s(@ffcn, [t_start, t_end], x(end, :));
    t = [t; t_sol(2 : end)];
    x = [x; x_sol(2 : end, :)];
    t_start = t_end;
end
```

In the first iteration of the loop, `t_start` is 0 and `t_end` is the first switching point. We use `ode15s` now to only integrate over this interval, and our `ffcn` evaluates the ODE with `u(1)`. The solution `y_sol` and the corresponding time points `t_sol` are appended to our overall solution (`t`, `x`).

For the next iteration, we set `t_start` to the end of the current segment and set the new `t_end` to the next switching point. You can also see that the last element of `t_seg` must be the time at which the simulation ends. Importantly, we pass to `ode15s` the current tail `y(end, :)` of the simulated trajectory as the initial state vector of the next segment.

In summary, the function `model` will use `ode15s` to simulate the model segment by segment and return the overall trajectory `y` and its time points `t`. You could convince yourself with an example like

```
[t, x] = model1(1, [4, 6, 12], [0.4, -0.7, 0.3]);
plot(t, x);
```

which for my exponential growth example should yield

[image: Simulation Result]

For your optimization runs, you will need to write an objective function. This objective function can pass `u` to `model`, and then calculate the merit associated with `u` by looking at `x`.