# Matlab ode15s change parameter value at specific time during solution

Tags: matlab, variables, differential-equations

I'm trying to change the value of my variable Pin at specific points in time during the ode15s solution, in order to evaluate the dynamic response. But I get the error:

```
Error using odearguments (line 83)
The last entry in tspan must be different from the first entry.
```

I believe the error is somewhere here:

```
t_start=0;
    t=t_start;
    y=cond;

    while idx_seg< length(t_seg)
        idx_seg=idx_seg+1;
        t_end=t_seg(idx_seg);    
    [t_sol,y_sol]=ode15s(@(t,y)f1_v1,[t_start, t_end],y(end,:));
    t = [t; t_sol(2 : end)];
    y = [y; y_sol(2 : end, :)];
    t_start = t_end;
    end
```

Here's the full code:

```
    function [t,y]=f2_v4_21_08_18(cond, t_seg, Pin)

         % -----Constants -----

             N=3.38*10^6; k=2.96*10^-7; alphat=2.6*10^-5; chb=0.2; M=30*10^-9; K=5*10^(-8)*10^-3; H=0.42; S0=0.98; 
    bp=0.8; ro=1040*10^6; 
    Ey=10^4*0.00750062; 
    v=3* 7.5*10^-6; 

    r=[0.0119850000000000;0.00958500000000000;0.00764000000000000;0.00604000000000000;0.00473000000000000;0.00366000000000000;0.00400000000000000;0.00575500000000000;0.00726500000000000;0.00889500000000000;0.0107250000000000;0.0128500000000000;0.0153850000000000]; %mm
    L=[1.27076497943190;0.932650928622621;0.544932761536915;0.303082765473283;0.161799106136796;0.155424891414508;0.245072221621871;0.475103125625241;0.273016623935407;0.427646038844292;0.634082325832342;0.846354695529459;0.938696601022114]; %mm
    h=[0.00484000000000000;0.00425000000000000;0.00381000000000000;0.00349000000000000;0.00327000000000000;0.00314000000000000;0.000309000000000000;0.00115000000000000;0.00145000000000000;0.00178000000000000;0.00215000000000000;0.00257000000000000;0.00308000000000000];%mm
    mu=[1.19409872390289e-05;1.12760032450214e-05;1.06583134073916e-05;1.00804835896938e-05;9.56162410894012e-06;9.20633512007761e-06;9.29628357913371e-06;9.96996247072375e-06;1.05291656347798e-05;1.10660983739492e-05;1.16035344790804e-05;1.21594980256614e-05;1.27473361251949e-05]; %mmHg*s
    R= [1.8728    3.1728    4.3411    5.8457    7.8705   20.3059   22.6623   10.9961    2.6277    1.9250    1.4161    0.9612    0.5439]; %[mmHg*s/ml]
    pdrop=[0,6.93,5.87,4.02,2.70,1.82,2.35,2.62,1.27,0.61,0.89,1.31,1.78,2.01];
    n=[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]; 
    %%%%%

    idx_seg=0;

    function dy= f1_v1(t,y)
    dy=zeros(13,1);

    pt1=y(1); pt2=y(2); pt3=y(3); pt4=y(4);  pt5=y(5);  pt6=y(6);  pt7=y(7);  pt8=y(8);  pt9=y(9);  pt10=y(10);  pt11=y(11);  pt12=y(12);  pt13=y(13);

     % -----Constants -----
...
    R= [1.8728    3.1728    4.3411    5.8457    7.8705   20.3059   22.6623   10.9961    2.6277    1.9250    1.4161    0.9612    0.5439]; %[mmHg*s/ml]
    pdrop=[0,6.93,5.87,4.02,2.70,1.82,2.35,2.62,1.27,0.61,0.89,1.31,1.78,2.01];


      for i=1:1:14
        if i==1
            pb(i)=Pin(idx_seg);
        else
        pb(i)=pb(i-1)-pdrop(i);
        end
        pb(i)=pb;
      end

    diffp=diff(pb)*(-1);
    pb_s=[pb(1)+pb(2);pb(2)+pb(3);pb(3)+pb(4);pb(4)+pb(5);pb(5)+pb(6);pb(6)+pb(7);pb(7)+pb(8);pb(8)+pb(9); pb(9)+pb(10);pb(10)+pb(11);pb(11)+pb(12);pb(12)+pb(13);pb(13)+pb(14)];

    for z=1:1:14
        S(z)=(((pb(z)^3+150*pb(z))^(-1) *23400)+1)^(-1);
    end
    deltaS=diff(S)*(-1);

    for j=1:1:13
        kin=v;
        compl(j)=((3*pi*L(j)*r(j)^3)/(2*Ey*h(j)) )*10^-3; 
        Vb(j)=(compl(j)/2)*pb_s(j); %[ml]
        q(j)=diffp(j)/R(j);
        Vt(j)= chb*H*q(j)*deltaS(j)/M;
    end

    %%differential eq
    dpt1=1/(alphat*Vt(1))*( (2*pi*K*r(1)*L(1))/h(1) *(1/2*(pb(1)+pb(2)) -pt1) -M*Vt(1));
    dpt2=1/(alphat*Vt(2))*( (2*pi*K*r(2)*L(2))/h(2) *(1/2*(pb(2)+pb(3)) -pt2) -M*Vt(2));
    dpt3=1/(alphat*Vt(3))*( (2*pi*K*r(3)*L(3))/h(3) *(1/2*(pb(3)+pb(4)) -pt3) -M*Vt(3));
    dpt4=1/(alphat*Vt(4))*( (2*pi*K*r(4)*L(4))/h(4) *(1/2*(pb(4)+pb(5)) -pt4) -M*Vt(4));
    dpt5=1/(alphat*Vt(5))*( (2*pi*K*r(5)*L(5))/h(5) *(1/2*(pb(5)+pb(6)) -pt5) -M*Vt(5));
    dpt6=1/(alphat*Vt(6))*( (2*pi*K*r(6)*L(6))/h(6) *(1/2*(pb(6)+pb(7)) -pt6) -M*Vt(6));
    dpt7=1/(alphat*Vt(7))*( (2*pi*K*r(7)*L(7))/h(7) *(1/2*(pb(7)+pb(8)) -pt7) -M*Vt(7));
    dpt8=1/(alphat*Vt(8))*( (2*pi*K*r(8)*L(8))/h(8) *(1/2*(pb(8)+pb(9)) -pt8) -M*Vt(8));
    dpt9=1/(alphat*Vt(9))*( (2*pi*K*r(9)*L(9))/h(9) *(1/2*(pb(9)+pb(10)) -pt9) -M*Vt(9));
    dpt10=1/(alphat*Vt(10))*( (2*pi*K*r(10)*L(10))/h(10) *(1/2*(pb(10)+pb(11)) -pt10) -M*Vt(10));
    dpt11=1/(alphat*Vt(11))*( (2*pi*K*r(11)*L(11))/h(11) *(1/2*(pb(11)+pb(12)) -pt11) -M*Vt(11));
    dpt12=1/(alphat*Vt(12))*( (2*pi*K*r(12)*L(12))/h(12) *(1/2*(pb(12)+pb(13)) -pt12) -M*Vt(12));
    dpt13=1/(alphat*Vt(13))*( (2*pi*K*r(13)*L(13))/h(13) *(1/2*(pb(13)+pb(14)) -pt13) -M*Vt(13));
    pt_tot=[pt1;pt2;pt3;pt4;pt5;pt6;pt7;pt8;pt9;pt10;pt11;pt12;pt13];


    dy=[dpt1;dpt2;dpt3;dpt4;dpt5;dpt6;dpt7;dpt8;dpt9;dpt10;dpt11;dpt12;dpt13];
    end

    t_start=0;
    t=t_start;
    y=cond;

    while idx_seg< length(t_seg)
        idx_seg=idx_seg+1;
        t_end=t_seg(idx_seg);    
    [t_sol,y_sol]=ode15s(@(t,y)f1_v1,[t_start, t_end],y(end,:));
    t = [t; t_sol(2 : end)];
    y = [y; y_sol(2 : end, :)];
    t_start = t_end;
    end


    for i=1:1:14
        if i==1
            pb=Pin(idx_seg);
        else
        pb(i)=pb(i-1)-pdrop(i);
        end
    end

    diffp=diff(pb)*(-1);
    pb_s=[pb(1)+pb(2);pb(2)+pb(3);pb(3)+pb(4);pb(4)+pb(5);pb(5)+pb(6);pb(6)+pb(7);pb(7)+pb(8);pb(8)+pb(9); pb(9)+pb(10);pb(10)+pb(11);pb(11)+pb(12);pb(12)+pb(13);pb(13)+pb(14)];

    for z=1:1:14
        S(z)=(((pb(z)^3+150*pb(z))^(-1) *23400)+1)^(-1);
    end
    deltaS=diff(S)*(-1);

    for j=1:1:13
        kin=v;
        compl(j)=((3*pi*L(j)*r(j)^3)/(2*Ey*h(j)) )*10^-3; %vessel compliance   (ElBouri2018) [ml/mmHg]   
        Vb(j)=(compl(j)/2)*pb_s(j); %[ml]
        q(j)=diffp(j)/R(j);
        Vt(j)= chb*H*q(j)*deltaS(j)/M;
    end

    for m=1:1:13
                  pt_weight(m)=y_sol(m)*Vt(m);
               end
               Vttot=Vt.*n;
    Vt_sum=sum(Vttot);
    ptot=sum(1/Vt_sum * (pt_weight));

    end
```

These are the initial conditions and times I run it with:

```
cond=[51.2112  ; 63.8766  ; 60.7979  ; 49.0010 ;  35.3767 ;  28.5718  ; 33.7930 ;  31.1300 ;  30.6594  ; 29.9741 ;  30.2541  ; 29.6828  ; 28.9798 ]; 
 [t, y] = f2_v4_21_08_18(cond, [0, 10, 100], [60, 70, 60]);
plot(t, y);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are the values of tspan at the time the error occurs? use the debug tools to find out.

Comment: thanks. It appears to occur immediately at t=0, but I don't understand why since I used the exact same method as proposed in another question here. This worked perfectly:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289109/ode-15s-with-time-dependent-input-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Check the first iteration of your while loop:

`idx_seg=idx_seg+1;
t_end=t_seg(idx_seg);
[t_sol,y_sol]=ode15s(@(t,y)f1_v1,[t_start, t_end],y(end,:));`

What happens? `idx_seg` was initialized to zero, gets set to one, i.e., `t_end` is set to `t_seg(1)`, its first element. You passed the vector `[0,10,100]` for `t_seg` in your call to `f2_v4_21_08_18`. Therefore, in your first iteration, `t_end` is equal to zero.

Now, `t_start` is also zero, i.e., you are asking `ode15s` to run the time interval from `t_start` to `t_end` which are both zero. Therefore, it complains that `The last entry in tspan must be different from the first entry.`

Solution: Pass a different time span vector, i.e., `[1, 10, 100]` should already solve the problem. The example you copied from used `[4,6,12]`. Make it match your problem.

**edit**: Having checked again what you're doing, here is another piece of advice: the way to interpret `t_seg` is that it contains the time points where the parameter **changes**. For `t_seg = [4,6,12]` it means that from 0 to 4 the parameter `u(1)` is active, from 4 to 6 it is `u(2)` and from 6 to 12 it is `u(3)`. Passing `[0,10,100]` and `[60,70,60]` would mean it changes from 60 to 70 right away, and then back to 60. This would be the same as passing `[10,100]` and `[70,60]`.