# ode using events to input external variable into equations

Tags: matlab, variables, events, external, ode

I try to figure out how to input external variables(changing with time - hormone levels) into ode. 
I'm thinking about using events. I try to do optimisation (optimilisation of differential equations in Matlab with built-in events)

In order to learn how to use them I've tried to run code in [Matlab ode solvers: changing state and specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356037/matlab-ode-solvers-changing-state-and-specified-time)
However, I do sth wrong. I guess that the problem is with my function myfun, but I don't know why.

I've tried to run following:

```
           function ydot=myfun(t,y,a)

           S1 = 2 *a* 2 * y(2)  -  2 * 3 * y(1)*y(1);
           S2 = 3 * y(1)*y(1) + a -  5 * y(2);
           ydot = [S1; S2];
           y_0=[0,0];
           %[t,y]=ode45(@myfun,[0:0.1:Tfinal],y_0);


and run following with nested myfun function:


%function events=events_in_Matlab(a)
       dt=0.01;
       T=0:dt:30;
       y_0=[0 0];
       Y=zeros(length(T),length(y_0));


       %t=0 to t=10, pass parameter a=0 to add to ODEs
       a=0;
       [~,Y(1:10/dt+1,:)]=ode45(@(t,y)myfun(t,y,a),T(1:10/dt+1),y_0);
       %t=10 to t=20, pass parameter a=10 to add to ODEs
       a=10;
       [~,Y(10/dt+1:20/dt+1,:)]=ode45(@(t,y)myfun(t,y,a),T(10/dt+1:20/dt+1),
       Y(10/dt+1,:));
       %t=20 to t=30, pass parameter a=20 to add to ODEs
       a=20;

      [~,Y(20/dt+1:end,:)]=ode45(@(t,y)myfun(t,y,a),T(20/dt+1:end),(20/dt+1,:));
```

Comment: you need to perform interpolation since the step size is not fixed inside ode45.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is right but your differential equation might not be ok.

First, your last equation is missing a "Y", it should be:

`[~,Y(20/dt+1:end,:)]=ode45(@(t,y)myfun(t,y,a),T(20/dt+1:end),Y(20/dt+1,:));`

Second, it seems that this is a stiff system of differential equations. I suggest you to use another solver, for example `ode23s` instead of `ode45`. In this way I managed to obtain a solution (with a lot of warnings due to near singular matrix).

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, I've corrected a missing Y, but still get a series or errors and it doesn't run. I try to execute events_in_Matlab, as function myfun is nested into ode but a get a following error messages and it doesn't run:  Undefined function or variable 'myfun'.

Error in events_in_matlab>@(t,y)myfun(t,y,a)
Error in odearguments (line 87)

 Do I try to run in improper way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I run it like this:

In the main file

`dt=0.01;
T=0:dt:30;
y_0=[0 0];
Y=zeros(length(T),length(y_0));

%t=10 to t=20, pass parameter a=10 to add to ODEs
a=10;
[T1,Y1]=ode23s(@(t,y)myfun(t,y,a),T(10/dt+1:20/dt+1),Y(10/dt+1,:));

plot(T1,Y1)`

And in the function to solve: 

`function ydot=myfun(t,y,a)
   S1 = 2 *a* 2 * y(2)  -  2 * 3 * y(1)*y(1);
   S2 = 3 * y(1)*y(1) + a -  5 * y(2);
   ydot = [S1; S2];
end`

Comment: Big thank you for explanation, it will let me start with more complex example which I have.

Comment: You´re welcome! Don't forget to mark the question as answered if your're ok with it!