# Pass in a vector into ode45 (MATLAB/Octave)

Tags: matlab, ode

I am having a function to solve by ode45. To make it easy, I will use this mock-up case to present my question:

The actual differential function is y' = f(time, y, current), while current is a function of time, that has a value at every time point. For example, time = [0.001, 0.002, 0.003] and current = [0.123, 0.456, 0.789]. However, when I use ode45, I have to write the function in the following format:

```
function dy = odefun(t, y)
dy = some code % some code calculates y' = f(time, y, current)
end
```

And therefore, I am stuck in how to pass in the parameter "current". It would be much easier if current is a constant, but it's not.

One workaround is to write a function getCurrent(time); however, that means I need to search the time vector, find a match and its index, and then return current. The searching process may take quite a long time to finish.

So, I was wondering, is there a more correct way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: One way or another you need to write some kind of `getCurrent(t)` function or lookup table. Unless you can calculate current directly as a function of your state variables `y` and time `t`? How was this current vector obtained?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How solve a system of ordinary differntial equation with time-dependent parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343563/how-solve-a-system-of-ordinary-differntial-equation-with-time-dependent-paramete)

Comment: @horchler Thank you for pointing me at the link! And also, the interp1 function is the way to go. Appreciate it!